# Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage, but it seems obvious

Tags: c#

Why does type inference not work in the following case when I call `DoSomething`?

```
    public class A { }
    public class B<T> { }
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void DoSomething<TWrapper, TInner>(this TWrapper thing)
        where TWrapper : B<TInner>
        {

        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            new B<A>().DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

It seems to me that in the `Test` method `TWrapper` has to be `B<A>`, so `TInner` has to be `A`. Why can't the compiler figure this out?

Comment: @RufusL Because I passed in an object of type `B<A>` into DoSomething.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write extensions for `B<T>` then it would simply be:

```
public class A { }
public class B<T>{}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(this B<T> thing) {}
}

public static void Test()
{
    var test = new B<A>();

    test.DoSomething();
}
```